# Can't open fasta file into phyDat format

Tags: r, file, bioinformatics, fasta, dna-sequence

I have been using the R phangorn package to open a fasta file into phyDat format to analyze.

I believe I have set up the file reading incorrectly:

```
dataFile <- file("primatesAA.meg")

phyData <- read.phyDat(dataFile, format = "fasta", type = "AA")
modelTest(dataFile, tree = NULL, model = "all", G = TRUE, I = TRUE,
      FREQ = FALSE, k = 4, control = pml.control(epsilon = 1e-08, maxit = 10,
                                                 trace = 1), multicore = FALSE, mc.cores 
           = NULL)
```

I got the following error message.

> dataFile <- file("primatesAA.meg")
> phyData <- read.phyDat(dataFile, format = "fasta", type = "AA")
> Error in if (ncol(data) == 1) compress <- FALSE :
> argument is of length zero
> In addition: Warning message:
> In read.FASTA(file, type = "AA") : failed to read sequences, returns NULL

Is there a correct way to set this up?

Comment: In the absence of a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's hard to say.  Are you certain your file is in FASTA AA format?  What happens if you try to use `read.FASTA("primatesAA.meg", type = "AA")` on its own?

Comment: The file extension `.meg` suggests a MEGA file, which as I understand it is slightly different from a base `fasta` file and has a header region, which would explain the issue.  `strataG` has a `read.mega()` function that might do the job, but I've not used it to confirm, just located it through searching.

Comment: That was an oversight on my part but there is a different error message when I enter a fasta file name.

Comment: Error in read.phyDat(dataFile, format = "fasta", type = "AA") : 
  sequences have different length

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13325/phangorn-fasta-file-read-error

Comment: I am using MEGA to align them, which produces a MAS file.  I don't see it as an option for the "format" field.  Would "sequential" format, for example, work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255582/discussion-between-t-j-foster-and-paul-stafford-allen).